# Layer Mask Issue - Player collides with Enemy even though layer masks have been changed (Unity, Bolt scripting)

Tags: unity-game-engine, collision-detection, game-physics

Please help, I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

I'm following the Bolt Unity tutorial. When colliding with the enemy, the player is supposed to change to an Invulnerable state, at which point the Player object should not collide with the Enemy game object until after the exit state. This is done by changing the Player layer mask to PlayerInvincible and unchecking the collision matrix for PlayerInvincible & Enemies. However, although the layer masks change in real time correctly (I've tested it by watching the flow graphs during play), the player object still collides with the enemy in my testing.

I've checked the collision matrix and as far as I can tell it's set up correctly. Below are timestamps from the tutorial and screenshots of my setup.

Here's the tutorial where they demonstrate the player/enemy collision working as intended: https://youtu.be/lb38XBNxvbA?list=PLIJZVV88CLcuyjeS3FE7yHtGps_zxBLf6&t=338

Here's where they set up the health state, switching the layer masks: https://youtu.be/olHvE27uvOI?list=PLIJZVV88CLcuyjeS3FE7yHtGps_zxBLf6&t=1027

Collision Matrix

[image]

Player Health State Setup

[image]

Player Mask settings

[image]

Enemy Mask settings

[image]

Player mask changes in real time as expected, however player still collides with enemy object

[image]

Answer (score 2):

What you show us in the first image looks like the settings for [`Physics (3D)`](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-PhysicsManager.html). I can see that since in [`Physics 2D`](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-Physics2DManager.html) there is e.g. no option `Enable Unified Height Maps` ;)

---

Note that Unity has two completely separated, independent, unrelated built-in [physics engines](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/PhysicsSection.html)

- Built-in 3D physics (Nvidia PhysX engine integration)
- Built-in 2D physics (Box2D engine integration)

Therefore there are also two different settings, one for 3D and one for 2D.

---

=> Since this is a 2D game using `Collider2D` components you have to configure the collision matrix for **`Physics2D`**!

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! That was the problem, now it works fine. As you can see, I'm quite new to unity :)

Comment: @AaronE glad to help! :) Please feel free to accept the answer ;)